# Profiling on Windows

Tags: profiling, racket

I started trying out things with Racket a few days ago, and now I'm stuck with the profiler.

The function I want to profile is called `my-fn`.

First thing I tried was to include `(require profile)` then call `(profile-thunk (thunk (my-fn arg1)))`.

When I hit the run button in DrRacket, it shows

```
Profiling results
-----------------
  Total cpu time observed: 0ms (out of 2ms)
  Number of samples taken: 0 (once every 0ms)

====================================
                        Caller
Idx  Total    Self    Name+srcLocal%
     ms(pct)  ms(pct)   Callee
====================================
```

then print the return value of `my-fn`.

I then tried to make my function slower by giving it more items in the arguments, and add the `#:repeat` option to the profiler.

`(profile-thunk (thunk (my-fn arg1)) #:repeat 5000)`

The result is now:

```
Profiling results
-----------------
  Total cpu time observed: 29488ms (out of 31641ms)
  Number of samples taken: 1687 (once every 17ms)

====================================
                        Caller
Idx  Total    Self    Name+srcLocal%
     ms(pct)  ms(pct)   Callee
====================================
```

Which seems to have done something good but I still can't see the results.

I then tried to use the command line (after having added `raco` to the `%PATH%`)

`raco profile .\test.rkt`

but I still get nothing good:

```
Profiling results
-----------------
  Total cpu time observed: 234ms (out of 281ms)
  Number of samples taken: 4 (once every 59ms)

====================================
                        Caller
Idx  Total    Self    Name+srcLocal%
     ms(pct)  ms(pct)   Callee
====================================
```

I'm all out of ideas, so anyone could share the right way to do it, please?

Sidenote, is it possible to have the profiler results come AFTER the return value of the function in DrRacket? Mine is a long list of number, I need to scroll up to see the (empty) profiler result. (It is not happening on the command line though so not very important)

Thanks

P.S.
I also tried to change the renderer with `(require profile/render-text)`

and `then (profile-thunk (thunk (my-fn arg1)) #:repeat 5000 #:renderer render)`

or `then (profile-thunk (thunk (my-fn arg1)) #:repeat 5000 #:renderer text:render)`

or `then (profile-thunk (thunk (my-fn arg1)) #:repeat 5000 #:renderer #'render)`

But I get error messages about `renderer` not being a function.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite exactly what I was hoping for, but I found a fix in the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/plt-scheme/hDh7dAk-GOg/gBU_SxAuZ8oJ).

To enable profiling in DrRacket:

- Go to Language | Choose Language
- Click on Show Details
- At the top-right, select "Debugging and profiling". (the default setting seems to be only debugging)

Then run some code in the console or with the "Run" button, and then:

- Go to View | Show profile

and at the bottom of the screen, profile information shows up. As far as I can see it doesn't handle thread very well ( printing `<<unknown>>37:28` for the line of the thread joining command `touch`) but it is always better that no profiler at all.

I still didn't resolve why I couldn't get the `profile-thunk` function nor the `profile` macro not the `profile` command of `raco` to work but it might be related to windows or my install?

Comment: Instead of giving `thread` an anonymous function created by `thunk`, you can give it a named function you `define`. This might give you friendlier output in the profiler.

Comment: Thanks for the tip